# Hide API information

Tags: javascript, axios, environment-variables, environment, netlify

I have successfully connected my static html form to my Airtable DB after following a short tutorial, I say follow.... more taking snippets to use in my own environment.

This worked perfectly but my API Information is on show in the html file.

The issue now is, they used Netlify, React and Gatsby and hid their API information using a .env.development.

I don't know these programs so I am getting way out of my depth.

I simply want a way to hide my api information and upload my html form so it can be used.

If I need to use a program like Netlify to do so then fine but I don't know it and having read information on it, I need to use a public Git repo and not I'm really a fan of having my stuff open the public especially if it's a customer's website.

Here's my JS (with API info replaced)

```
function getTodos() {
  app_id = "app123456789"
  app_key = "key123456789"
  table_id = "table123456789"
  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + app_key,
      'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
  };
  axios
    .get(
      "https://api.airtable.com/v0/" + app_id + "/" + table_id, axiosConfig)
    .then(resp => showOutput(resp))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many ways to do this, you need to do the API requests from a server of yours, which would act as a proxy between your client and the API endpoint.

Javascript => Your server => Airtable API

Comment: Thanks, this is what I don't understand, coding for me is more of a hobby. I code my html file and upload to my hosting provider that's as far as I go although I want to learn more.

Comment: It seems that your hosting provider directly serves html. What you need is your own web server though, usually people code that in PHP or Python. Can your hosting provider run python ?

Comment: I'm using https://www.guru.co.uk but again happily switch to something more suitable if you can recommend anyone?

Comment: you should probably contact the support and ask them if you can run your homemade code, without any framework or application.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the encrypted file to the server and decrypt there.
Just like how internet banking works. They encrypt the username and password and send to their server where they decrypt it.

Comment: How do I do this? Do I just upload a hidden file to my hosting / public_html folder?